# Unmarshall XML with attribute containing CDATA using JAXB2 OXM

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am trying to unmarshal an XML which looks like this:

==============================[XML]====================================

```
<Element1>
<innerElement attr1="value1">
    <ConcernedElement FirstAttribute="FirstValue" SecondAttribute="<![CDATA[<AttributeElement aAttribute="aValue" bAttribute="bValue"><vElement vAttrib="aV.Value"></vElement></AttributeElement>]]>"></ConcernedElement>
</innerElement>
</Element1>
```

The Schema Definition is as below:

==============================[XSD]=================================

```
<xs:element name="Element1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="innerElement" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="innerElement">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="ConcernedElement" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="ConcernedElement">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="FirstAttribute" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="SecondAttribute" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Whenever I tried to do unmarshall with this function:

```
public Object unmarshall(String xml) {
    try {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer(xml);
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(stringBuffer.toString());
        StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(stringReader);
        Object object = customUnmarshaller.unmarshal(streamSource);
        return object;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I get an exception that *SecondAttribute* contains an invalid character <.

===================[EXCEPTION THROWN]======================

```
ex = (org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException) org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 159; The value of attribute "SecondAttribute" must not contain the '<' character.]
```

Also, doing an XML Validation indicate that the XML is invalid.

Is there something else I need to do or a config that I'm missing out?
How do I resolve this?

Comment: did you solve it? I get the same problem.

Comment: What I did was to escape the value of the SecondAttribute and replace the    original value in the XML String with the escaped value... This way the Marshaller is able to unmarshall the whole XML and the SecondAttribute retrieved correctly as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to solve in a way.

What I did was to escape the value of the *SecondAttribute* and replace the    original value in the XML String with the escaped value... This way, the Marshaller is able to unmarshall the whole XML and the *SecondAttribute* retrieved correctly as well.

```
public String getEscappedConcernedElementXML(String sourceXML) {
    String concernedElementXMLString = findConcernedElementInXML(sourceXML);
    if (concernedElementXMLString == null || (concernedElementXMLString.equal(""))) {
        return concernedElementXMLString;
    }

    concernedElementXMLString = escapeSecondAttributeValueInXML(corcernedElementXMLString);

    return concernedElementXMLString;
}


public String escapeSecondAttributeValueInXML(String sourceXML) {
    String secondAttributeStartCursor = "SecondAttribute=\"";
    int secondAttributeIndex = sourceXML.indexOf(secondAttributeStartCursor);

    String secondAttributeEndCursor = "\">";
    int secondAttributeEndIndex = sourceXML.indexOf(secondAttributeEndCursor, secondAttributeIndex);


    String secondAttributeValue = sourceXML.substring(secondAttributeIndex + secondAttributeStartCursor.length(), secondAttributeEndIndex);
    String escappedSecondAttributeValue = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(secondAttributeValue);

    return sourceXML.replace(secondAttributeValue, escappedSecondAttributeValue);
}
```

Then, unmarshalling the XML will give the appropriate Object with the attributes' values.